# ¿Como puedo mostrar dos registros de una misma columna?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy practicando e iniciandome en MYSQL y uno de los ejercicios que encontré era crear una tabla con empleados y sus respectivos datos. Lo que necesito hacer es obtener los empleados con los apellidos PEREZ y LOPEZ.

Lo puedo hacer de la siguiente manera pero quiero hacerlo en una sola linea.

```
SELECT * 
FROM empleados 
WHERE apellidos = "LOPEZ";

SELECT * 
FROM empleados 
WHERE apellidos = "PEREZ";
```

Esta es la tabla de empleados:

```
+----------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| Clave_empleado | Nombre    | Apellidos | Clave_depto |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| EMP01          | ARMANDO   | LOPEZ     |           2 |
| EMP02          | TATIANA   | VARGAS    |           1 |
| EMP03          | LAURA     | ITURRIA   |           3 |
| EMP04          | JUAN      | PEREZ     |           4 |
| EMP05          | IVAN      | LOPEZ     |           4 |
| EMP06          | MARGARITA | HERNANDEZ |           1 |
| EMP07          | JESUS     | PEREZ     |           3 |
| EMP08          | LAUTARO   | FLORES    |           2 |
| EMP09          | JUAN      | LOPEZ     |           4 |
| EMP10          | JOSE      | HERNANDEZ |           5 |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Saludos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select * 
from empleados 
where apellidos = "López" or apellidos = "Pérez";
```

Aquí haces uso del **operador lógico or**. Este operador muestra un registro si alguna de las condiciones separadas por el operador es verdadera.

Comment: Gracias! estuve utilizando el operador "and" pero el correcto era "or".